# Specify using namespace in class constructore

Tags: c++, namespaces

I'm not sure what is the best approach, but I'm trying to determine which `namespace` to use as a constructor class is made. Furthermore, I'm using overloading to select which contrustor is used.

```cpp
// foo.hpp
class A
{
public:
A(int a);
A(bool a);
};

namespace alice {
   void read();
}
namespace bob {
   void read();
}

void somefunction();
```

```cpp
//foo.cpp
A::A(int a)
{
 using namespace alice;
}

A::A(bool a)
{
 using namespace bob;
}

namespace alice {
    void read()
    {
         // Do something
    }
}


namespace bob{
    void read()
    {
         // Do something else
    }
}

void someFunction()
{
    // EXPECTING TO BE USING THE NAMESPACE THAT WAS DECLARED IN THE CLASS
    read();
}
```

I'm sure I'm going about this all wrong, but this is just a thought in order to reuse the A class in multiple similar projects depending on which constructor is used

Comment: You can't do that, use a function pointer instead

Comment: or a template argument